# Taking input through serial port by bits

Tags: c, input, serial-port

I want to take digital input through serial port as a high level of 5V and low level of 0V or maybe as the computer defaults as -12V to +12V. But I will not follow the USART protocol I want to make my own protocol to transfer signal from a avr to my pc through serial port. Can I do it? In windows.

Comment: A serial port has strict timing requirements for the signal it recognizes. If you don't adhere to it you won't be able to do anything useful with it.

Comment: The question is **clear** - assuming one understands UART protocols and why the voltages are mentioned _and_ programming, interrupts, etc.  The challenge is that this query lies in the _middle_ of a Electrical Engineer question and a programming question - thus it belongs in neither or both forums.  Having myself worked through this question in the past helps make the issues clear.  Yes - its not a great fit for SO,  but it is _just_ close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  Receive Data (RD) net on a serial port adheres to strict timing requirements based on the baud, parity, and stop bit settings.  There is no feasible way to use that net for a non-USART protocol.

The controls lines 'carrier Detect (CD), Data Set ready (DTR),  Clear to send (CTS) and maybe even Ring Indicator (RI) offer *some* promise.  These control lines in virtual serial ports sometimes have various timing time delays that prevent their use in high speed data.

So if you were to sample these control lines at a high rate or set up interrupt routines that fire on change, you may, with a fair amount of work, implement the protocol of your choosing - espsially if your data rate is low.

Good luck should you attempt this path.